# Layout margin/padding at the top of dialog fragment

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

When using fragments my layouts get disturbed by an additional space at the top and I don't know where this is coming from. It looks like this:

[image]

What are possible sources for this empty space? The theme or some style settings I have not yet found, or is this space reserved for an action bar? I would really like to get rid of this.

Here are the corresponding layout xml and the code to instantiate the dialog:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ProgressBar
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/search_progress"
            android:text="Searching for:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/searchingNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/search_progress"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Barcelona" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
mSearchingDialog = new SearchingDialogFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", mCityToAdd.userName());
mSearchingDialog.setArguments(bundle);
mSearchingDialog.show(fm, TAG);
```

I also asked this question here, thinking it would be a problem correlated with a scrollview, but the space appears in all my fragments:

[ScrollView adds extra space on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361857/scrollview-adds-extra-space-on-top)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a DialogFragment without title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277460/how-to-create-a-dialogfragment-without-title)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try to call `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` right **before** `setContentView(R.layout.<dialog_layout>);` in `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` method of your dialog.

Comment: Thank you, but the fragment does not have a getWindon() method. The code above is all I do to instantiate the dialog fragment, so there is no onCreate() either.

Comment: To access window call, getActivity().getWindow(). Call it in onCreateView() method.

Comment: I did `getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in the `onCreateView()` method and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 22):

There are two ways to reuse/remove that empty space at the top of the `DialogFragment`.

**If you want to simple remove it:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //  <--
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

**If you want to reuse it for a dialog title:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     getDialog().setTitle("Some title..."); //  <--
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
     return view;
}
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, because `getWindow()` doesn't wok in a `DialogFragment`

Answer (score 5):

Yet another solution:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, getActivity().getApplicationInfo().theme);
    }
```

This example uses the applications default theme. Note also that `setStyle()` needs to be called in `onCreate()` as opposed to `onCreateView()` to have an effect.

Comment: I used `setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog)`, because `theme` from `getActivity().getApplicationInfo()` removes transparent black overlay.